# Does Tesseract OCR engine support image deskewing and segmentation?

Tags: image-processing, tesseract, image-segmentation

I want to know if Tesseract 3.0 includes any image preprocessing, especially image deskewing and segmentation. If yes, what are more features that Tesseract includes?